# what is the problem with android while downloading? can any one figure out?

Tags: android

The following link downloads a file from a site.it works fine in desktop browser. but it is not working in android default browser and in webview code(i used download listener too but not working).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the Android default browser can't download .zip files by default (you should get a "This content is not supported" error).

If you want to download certain files through your own application though, you can try this [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507101/how-do-i-permit-the-android-browser-to-download-files-of-a-particular-extension).

Answer (score 0):

What code do you use? Could you specify it? I suggest you downloading it in AsyncTask via HTTP. Where do you save it? What is the error log? So many questions =)