# ACTION_VIEW with file download uri is not working (Chrome + Samsung S6)

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent

I try following code on my phone:

```
public static void install(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://github.com/MFlisar/EverywhereLauncherExtension/raw/master/extension.apk"));
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

If I copy the link into chrome, it works fine and starts the download. If I call `install(context)` chrome just opens the link, but does not start the download, instead it just closes the tab...

How can I solve that? I want that the browser downloads the file for me and the user can install the app afterwards.

*Info*

- my app does NOT have internet permissions nor do I want to add them just for downloading one file in my app internally.
- my minSDK is API 16, my target SDK is API 26

**Solutions - NOT working reliably**

1. Tried using a homepage link instead of the file link (https://github.com/MFlisar/EverywhereLauncherExtension). This works, if the user does not have installed a third party app that handles github links. Then the browser opens and the user can click the download link himself and it works. If a third party app is installed, the link opens in this app and if the user clicks the download link, the user sees the same behaviour as described above

**EDIT**

Seems like this only happens on my own phone, can't reproduce this in the emulator. But what I describe above happens on my Samsung S6 Edge running Android 7. Maybe anyone does have an idea why this happens on my device?

Comment: Sorry for asking but how can you download a file from the net without internet connection?

Comment: My app does not have permissions to use the internet, other apps like the browser of course have the permissions so I just want to delegate the download to a browser app...

Comment: What is your api level?

Comment: Min SDK = 16, Target SDK = 26...

Comment: Can you try like this  Uri webpage = Uri.parse(url);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }

Comment: Notice the Intent constructor having both the action and the url

Comment: As I wrote above, the activity is resolved, Otherwise chrome would not open (or any other app that is associated with the URI). I tried both ways (constructor with uri and constructor without, but with `setData`), both work the same and have the same result

Comment: I think it's a security feature of chrome, but I have no alternative idea currently to download a file...

Comment: Check this link. I think configuring the intent filter will solve your problem  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507101/how-do-i-permit-the-android-browser-to-download-files-of-a-particular-extension

Comment: This intent filter is placed in the manifest of the browser app and will only influence if the browser app handles my intent or not (and it does apparently, so the filter is fine)

Comment: Ok does your browser able to download other types of files besides the apk files.Can you check? FIrst thing first clear out the file type argument from this

Comment: I can copy the link into the browser and it can download it. Like any other file as well

Comment: Ok just got your solution. Have you given permission for storage?

Comment: You understand that all I do is following: "Dear android, I have a url, handle it with your default app" and that's it? The rest is up to android (it desides which app should handle the intent) and to the selected app (it decides, what to do and is responsible for everything else (permissions, handling data). I'm not doing anything in my app other than creating the intent and send it to the android system

Comment: Yes i understand also For some reason my browser is able to download the very apk that you are pointing.Some settings on your phone is not correct it seems. Try to do in emulator

Comment: I have downloaded from emulator as well as phone using google chrome

Comment: As I said, I think it's a problem with chrome. And even chrome can download it, if I add the url manually instead of via an intent. Did you try using a demo app with an intent or just the url? The url is working, I know that

Comment: Demo app and it is working on both emulator and my phone. you can check for now on emulator and see if it is working on that and also check with another guys phone because it is working on mine

Comment: Just added on newly created app on OnCreate method Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://github.com/MFlisar/EverywhereLauncherExtensions/raw/master/extension.apk"));
        startActivity(i);

Comment: @WebInsight thanks. I now could check this with an emulator myself and can see that it should actually work... Weird, that it's not working on my samsung s6 running android 7... I could not find any setting in chrome which could be responsible for this issue...

Comment: Check this link maybe it will help https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00048482/

Comment: I've enabled all but contacts permissions, so the important storage permission is given,..

Comment: I too am having this issue but it's not just with my samsung as it also doesn't work with my Tecno Y3 phone.  I have tested and if you use the phone's default browser and not Chrome then it will work. So it must be something new with Chrome